# How to detect undetected hard drive volume in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, hardware, hardware-raid

I have a Dell PowerEdge 2650 and I'm running Windows Server 2003.  Here is some back ground on the hardware of this Dell PE 2650.

I have 4 (not 5) 17GB RAID drives and has set up two containers. In the first container (17GB) I have drive-0 and drive-1 as RAID 1 Mirror for OS/System Drive and in second container (34GB) I have drive-2 and drive-3 as 'VOLUME'.  I realized that Windows Server 2003 didn't recognize the second container drive space.
How can I make Windows detect my 34gig volume?

Comment: What do you mean by "container" and how are drives 2 and 3 configured?

Comment: Dell BIOS Raid Manager gave me option to build containers by type (raid1, raid5, volume, etc).  Drives 2 and 3 are configured as 'VOLUME'.

Comment: By VOLUME I mean simple volume (JBOD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Device Manager, under Disk drives does it list the Dell container? If so, then go to Disk Management, right click and select Rescan Disks. If not, then try updating the PERC drivers and firmware.

Answer (score 0):

I did it pretty "crude" way.  Booted from Windows Installation Disc and Selected the problem container as install drive and Windows install gave me an option to quick format as NTFS.  Solved the problem.  Made sure I formatted the drive from inside Windows again just to make sure.